# $@ stores every argument into the first index

Tags: bash

So, in a script I have this at the top:

```sh
declare -ar OPT=$1
shift
declare -ar FLAGS=$@
```

And then, later in the script it has this:

```sh
echo ${FLAGS[0]}
```

So, if you use `commandname opt flag1 flag2 flag3`, you would expect it to echo `flag1`, but instead, it echos every argument, `flag1 flag2 flag3`. This clearly isn't supposed to happen, but I have no idea why it happens.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even if the array attribute on `FLAGS` is set, assigning to the name with a regular assignment still just assigns something to the first element. You want

```
declare -ar FLAGS=("$@")
```

You might notice the `-a` option becomes redundant, as any assignment of the form `x=(...)` automatically sets the array attribute.